# OpenGL/GLUT: glTranslatef and glRotatef before drawing cube, or after?

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, rotation, glut

I'm currently working with OpenGL and GLUT frameworks to play with particles.

However, I can seem to get my logic working correctly for the rotations/translations.

Pseudo code of my current situation:

```
void display() {
     drawEnvironment();

     for each particle 'part' in the array {
          glPushMatrix(); // pushes the matrix for the current transformations? i.e. this particle?

          glRotatef(part.angles); // rotate this matrix based of it's own angles (constantly changing)

          drawParticle(part); // draws at origin

          glTranslatef(part.positon); // translate to the position

          glPopMatrix();
     }
}
```

What I think I'm doing here is as follows:

1. Pushing the transformation matrix I need from the stack (for the current particle)
2. Rotating said matrix (glRotatef rotates around the origin (0,0,0) )
3. Drawing the particle at origin so it rotates on spot
4. Translate the particle to it's position now that it's been rotated
5. Pop the transformation matrix back onto the stack

I've also tried translating -> rotating -> drawing, and a few other mixes.

Hard to explain what's going wrong without a quick video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0ouhCKKcIM

Looks like it's rotating *after* it's being translated, so since it rotates around the origin it follows that larger circle, rather than spinning on it's own axis.

Comment: Transformations are applied in the process of drawing. Making any change to the transformation matrices after drawing has not effect. OpenGL is just some sophisticated pencil to draw onto a digital canvas and once a part of the picture is drawn, OpenGL already forgot about it.

Answer (score 2):

The transformations should be applied in this order:

1. Push the matrix from stack
2. Translate to position
3. Rotate it
4. Draw it
5. Pop the matrix

This is because OpenGL works by pre-multiplication. The first operation is performed last.

Comment: Perfect thank you! Turns out I had this exact order, except my issue was when I was playing around with the orders. In this case, I was translating to a coord "point" which was equal to the particle's position. Later (after translate & rotate), when drawing the particle at position, I forgot to reset "point" to the origin, so essentially I was almost drawing at (position.x + position.x, position.y + position.y, position.z + position.z)